# Csv import and changing locale of server

Tags: csv, locale

On my imports, if first character of row is special it miss. For example; "Çanta" importing like "anta". I searched and the problem is about locale. I use centos on my server and my locale properties is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I want to use Turkish charaters. How can I change my locale to avoid this csv import problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the locale using [`setlocale`](http://man.flashnux.com/en/centos/5/5.6/man3p/setlocale.3p.html).